# Reading raw PCM samples from an MP3 file using QtMultimedia?

Tags: qt, mp3, pcm, audio-processing

Is there a way to use QtMultimedia to access the PCM raw audio samples of MP3 files stored on a, say, Nokia N950 phone?

If it is not possible, what would be the reasonable alternative. Something which could be reasonably easily integrated with an existing Qt project. I know of libmpg123, but I am somewhat confused as to how to cross-compile it for the phone and I was hoping for something more straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as there is no better answer within several months, I'll provide one of my own.

After scouting all of the QtMultimedia I figured that it does not provide these functions and ended up using [libmpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/api/modules.shtml). It turned out to be possible to reuse just the raw mp3 file reading functions (`mpg123_open`, `mpg123_seek`, `mpg123_read`, `mpg123_close`) without having to link with any of the external libraries, which was good enough for my purposes.